# const value between class components in React

Tags: reactjs, components, constants

I have a class component which renders a const. all the values needed for its evaluation are inside that component. However for purposes of splitting up and keeping the code clean, it is used in another class component. How do i connect them?

Code:

```
Class component1 extends React.Component
///code

render() {
 const {allFacts, currentPage, factsPerPage } = this.state
 const indexOfLastFact = currentPage * factsPerPage
 const indexOfFirstFact = indexOfLastFact - this.state.factsPerPage
 const allFactsSliced = allFacts.slice(indexOfFirstFact, indexOfLastFact) <-- THIS
}

/// 
export default component1
```

the last const, allFactsSliced, is then used in another component:

```
Class component2 extends React.Component
///code

render() {
const renderAllFacts = 
    this.state.isLoading ? <div id="loading">///</div> :
    allFactsSliced.map((fact, index) =>                      <--- HERE
    {return <div>Fact # {index +1}: <br/> {fact.fact}</div>})
```

is this possible, good practice, or am i just needlesly complicating things and should keep everything in one component?

Comment: `or am i just needlesly complicating things and should keep everything in one component?` Yes. Class is for objects. Anything you want to relate to that object you can keep in class declaration. If it is common for all keep it static. NO need to do all this

Answer (score 0):

You can pass information into React components either by props, context, or a pure JS function or object.

So, if you want to pass `allFactsSliced` (or any other data) from one component to another, you have to do that by either props or context (since that particular piece of data is derived from the state of a component, you can't do it by a pure JS function or object).

If you have a parent/child relationship between these components, then you can pass derived state from the parent to the child (here it would have to be `component1` to `component2`). If they are siblings, then you have to lift the state (see the React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

If it's more a grandparent or great-grandparent, then you can consider putting that derived state from `component1` into a context and having `component2` consume that context.

It's worth mentioning that you'll re-render any components that rely on that prop or context when it changes it, so it may be faster to keep it in one component. Or it might not be. Profile it and check if it matters.

But, if you want to pass a value from one component to another, it's always either as a prop or a context.